# Python 2.7 turtle error

Tags: python, module, turtle-graphics

I am having trouble with the turtle module.

When I use this in a file:

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Pen
```

It makes this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/admin/SkyDrive/Documents/turtle command game", line 1, in <module>
    import turtle
  File "C:/Users/admin/SkyDrive/Documents\turtle.py", line 8, in <module>
    p = turtle.pen()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'pen'
```

but when I do the same thing in the python shell, it works fine. I copied and pasted them and made sure that they were the same.

I also tried:

```
from turtle import *
t = Pen()
```

but it returned the same error, and when I did that in the shell, everything ran smoothly.

I even tried importing the `Pen()` function directly in a file:

```
from turtle import Pen
t = Pen()
```

but it had the same error, but when I did it in the shell, it worked.

I have python 2.7.7 and windows 8.1

Can anyone tell me what is going on here?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `"C:/Users/admin/SkyDrive/Documents\turtle.py"` don't call your file turtle.py

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you call your file `turtle.py` and now Python can't find oryginal `turtle` file in library.

Comment: not maybe it is in plain english in the error `C:/Users/admin/SkyDrive/Documents\turtle.py`.

Comment: I did not read carefully trackback :)